# jest + enyzme + useRef

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, mocking, enzyme

I have a component that looks like:

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import Modal from '@example-component-library/modal'
import ModalHeader from '@example-component-library/modal/header'
import ModalFooter from '@example-component-library/modal/footer'

const ExampleModal = () => { 
  const headerRef = useRef(null)
  ...
  return (
    <Modal
      headerRef={headerRef}
      isOpen={showModal}
      header={
        <ModalHeader closeModal={handleCloseModal} headerRef={headerRef} content="Modal Header"/>
      }
      footer={<ModalFooter closeModal={handleCloseModal} />}
    >
      Modal body stuff
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

Then I have a test:

```js
it('renders as expected', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <TestWrapper>
        <ExampleModal />
      </TestWrapper>
    )

    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

and then I have an error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

      28 |
      29 |   it('renders as expected', () => {
    > 30 |     const wrapper = mount(
         |                     ^
      31 |       <TestWrapper>
      32 |         <ExampleModal />
      33 |       </TestWrapper>
```

If I change `ExampleModal` prop `header` to:

```js
<Modal header={<>HEADER</>} ...>
```

The test works without issues - so I believe it has something to do with the `headerRef` I've tried `jest.spyOn` and a few other solutions - however I always get the same error.

## Modal Component Markup

```js
const ModalHeader = ({ headerRef, content, ...}) => (
  <div>
    <h5 tabIndex={-1} ref={headerRef}> {content}</h5>
    ... 
  </div>
)

const Modal = ({ id, isOpen, header, headerRef, children, ...}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const selectorId = `#${id}`
    const selectedElement: HTMLElement = document.querySelector(selectorId)
    // set focus to the header when modal is opened
    if (isOpen && headerRef.current) {
      headerRef.current.focus()

      // React Ref wasn't working for this case
      selectedElement.style.right = '0px'
      document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
      setPostAnimationState(true)
    }

    if (!isOpen && document.querySelector(selectorId)) {
      // React Ref wasn't working for this case
      document.body.style.overflow = 'auto'
      selectedElement.style.right = '-768px'
      setTimeout(() => {
        setPostAnimationState(false)
      }, 400)
    }
  }, [isOpen, headerRef, id])

  return (
    <div>
      ...
      {!!header && header}
      <div className="modal-content" ref={!header ? headerRef : null}>
       {children}
      </div>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Why do you pass `headerRef` to both the `Modal` and `ModalHeader`? Where are you spying on anything in tests? Can you update your question to include all relevant code? (`ModalHeader`, `ModalFooter`, test code, etc)

Comment: @DrewReese - updated my post with the component markup. I did not build the component, see how it's working and where the `style` is missing - I'm just not sure how to mock this or how to test it without using `shallow`. I'd like to use `mount`

Answer (score 1):

It actually had nothing to do with `ref`, it had to do with the `document.body`. So here is the test I have that works now:

```
it('renders as expected', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <TestWrapper>
        <ExampleModal />
      </TestWrapper>,
      { attachTo: document.body }
    )

    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true)
  })
})
```